# Does Team Viewer/AnyDesk or Chrome Remote Desktop protocols works like VNC or like RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, network-protocols

I'm familiar with two conncepts of accessing remote desktop:
a) Remote Framebuffer (like VNC), which snapshoting local rendered framebuffer, compressing image and sending it over network + reciving input data
b) remote drawcalls rendering (like X11 or RDP, SPICE), in which server sending to client just drawcalls, and framebuffer is rendered on client side.

Option b is much better in every way, but i'm curious how popular software like Time Viewer, AnyDesk or Chrome Remote Desktop works?

Comment: TeamViewer and AnyDesk built upon Remote Desktop protocols, they are different since they run over standard https protocols, which is the reason they don’t require port forwarding.

Comment: VNC was designed the way it was to achieve maximum compatibility across OS's with minimal customization of the client/server packages. it focused on the intersection between the vidcard hardware and software in a way that is, by necessity, the same across all OS's.  In doing so however, it makes any measures you might take to improve stability or performance across low-bandwidth/high-latency links unachievable. One note; Teamview/anydesk/ChromeRD all use reverse-tunneling to bypass firewalls and NATs.  that requires public server infrastructure.